# Explanation of the following strncpy call

Tags: c, sockets, strncpy

I am currently reading a book (Linux Socket Programming - BY EXAMPLE) and on page 45 The Author uses a strange use(call) of `strncpy` and I can not understand why it is also working:

```
strncpy(  adr_unix.sun_path,
          pth_unix,
          sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path ) - 1 ) [sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - 1] = 0;
```

I was expecting that it should be like this:

```
strncpy(    adr_unix.sun_path,
            pth_unix,
            sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path ) - 1 );

adr_unix.sun_path[sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - 1] = 0;
```

What kind of code use is here in the third argument of `strncpy`?:

```
sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path - 1 ) ) [sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - 1] = 0;
```

Comment: `man 3 strncpy` ? Or you are asking about the subscripting the returned pointer?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, the about the subscripting part.

Comment: *and on page 45 The Author uses a strange use(call) of `strncpy`* – it would help if you told what's "strange" about it.

Comment: `strncpy()` returns a pointer to where it has copied to, which is `adr_unix.sun_path` in your case. So `strncpy(adr_unix.sun_path, ....)[...] = 0` does exactly the same as your code snippet. Personally I would prefer your version

Comment: then it is just taking the returned pointer and subscripting it

Comment: @EugeneSh. I undestand now. I think it is an Ugly way of doing that.

Comment: That is a matter of opinion, even though I agree :)

Comment: That `sizeof (adr_unix.sun_path-1)` is highly suspect - I'd expect to see `(sizeof adr_unix.sun_path) - 1` (since the former should just be the same as `sizeof adr_unix.sun_path`).

Comment: @TobySpeight You right my Bad. it should be after . EDITED.

Comment: Assuming you know the size of the source buffer, here is a better and safer version: `strcpy(adr_unix.sun_path, pth_unix);` KISS principle.

Comment: Though in the spirit of the author of that book, you should definitely write `(sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - true)[strncpy(adr_unix.sun_path, pth_unix, sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - true )] = false;`. Everything else is too easy to read.

Comment: @Lundin I think it is too much for my Knowledge :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay attention that `strncpy` call terminates here

```
strncpy(adr_unix.sun_path,
        pth_unix,
        sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path ) - 1 )
```

So because `strncpy` returns destination (`adr_unix.sun_path`) that calls it's equivalent to yours

```
strncpy(    adr_unix.sun_path,
        pth_unix,
        sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path ) - 1 );

adr_unix.sun_path[sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - 1] = 0;
```

and third argument of `strncpy` call is only `sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path) - 1`

Comment: Does this apply to all c standards (99, 11, 17)?

Comment: There's nothing that says you can't do this sort of subscripting except that it makes for very confusing code which is why you usually don't see it done.

Comment: @MichaelB. yes, also C89

Comment: `strncpy(    adr_unix.sun_path,
        pth_unix,
        sizeof( adr_unix.sun_path - 1 ) );`  remove the extra parentheses or you fall into the same trap **-->>** `strncpy(    adr_unix.sun_path,
        pth_unix,
        sizeof adr_unix.sun_path - 1 );`